# Script that will locate the location of files in different machine in the network

Tags: powershell

```
$computers = Get-Content "U:\listofremotecomputers.txt"

$files = Get-Content "U:\lookforthisfiles.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force \\$computer\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |`
        Where-Object {
        ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -eq "$files") 
        } |`
        Select-Object Name,Directory |`
        Export-Csv U:\FoundFiles.csv -nti -append
    }
}
```

How can I list the files, and able to locate them in a remote server?
I have tried the code below, not working still. I just want to locate what ever file is define in lookforthisfiles.txt, instead of looking at them one by one.

```
ForEach ($computers in $computers) { invoke-command -computername $server  {Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $files }}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this without `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`? Perhaps it will fail and tell you something useful.

Comment: same,, Any advise what do i need to look for the files remotely?

Comment: I am surprised `\\$computer\ ` works even for your local computer. If you are an administrator on all the computers, and you know the computer only has one drive, then maybe you can use the administrative share by accessing `"\\$computer\c$"` . This will be incredibly slow to search the entire hard drive of every computer, for every file, one at a time. A faster way would make each computer search itself, and launch all the searches at the same time. e.g. configure PS Remoting on all, and use `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: This does not work for me..  ForEach ($computer in $computer) { invoke-command -computername $computer locate $filenames }

Comment: Can you be any more descriptive about how it's 'not working'?

Comment: in my files- where it contains the list of files that i want to find/to know there location so i can access them. They are residing in a diffrent directories where the location is unknown. I want to look for them. They are about 100 files.  In my computer or server, is the list of all my servers..,